# close java frame using code

Tags: java, events, swing, jframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically close a JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234912/how-to-programmatically-close-a-jframe)

I am developing a java GUI using JFrame. I want to close the GUI frame and dispose it off through code.
I have implemented :

```
topFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                emsClient.close();
            }
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            }
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            }
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }
        });`
```

How can I invoke the windowClosing event?? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Please look in below thread for the same purpose:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258099/how-to-close-a-java-swing-application-from-the-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
yourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

You can add that line in the constructor(Dont forget it).

Comment: Well, I think the OP wants to close it programmatically.

Comment: If so he just need to catch the event for closing and call dispose(). But i don't understand, why not just adding that method in the constructor. Some IDEs add it even automatically when creating a JFrame.

Answer (score 18):

This will programmatically trigger the window closing event:

```
topFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(topFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

If you want to close the frame you need to call:

```
topFrame.dispose();
```

Comment: See also this related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540354) regarding `JDialog`.

Answer (score 3):

How about invoking `dispose()` method?

Comment: Just tried, `dispose()` doesn't trigger a window closing event. It does close the window though.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class CloseFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JButton close = new JButton("Close me programmatically");
                final JFrame f = new JFrame("Close Me");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane( close );
                close.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        // make the app. end (programatically)
                        f.dispose();
                    }
                } );
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent [sscce](http://sscce.org/), but it won't trigger the questioner's `WindowListener`; I'm guessing that was was the goal, based on the accepted answer.

Comment: Just to go off-topic, thanks for adding the Mac. screen shot to the Nested Layout Example.  :)