# Java Swing app won't quit

Tags: java, swing

I have a Java application that opens up a JFrame and draws in it. The problem is that when I try to quit the application, by either closing the JFrame window (on my Mac or PC) or choosing Quit from the menu bar (on my Mac), the application just hangs. What's interesting is that this behavior only appeared after I added a JButton to my application. Here's my 
code:

```
public class MyApplicationFrame extends JFrame {

public MyApplicationFrame(MyApplicationLogic l) {
    super();
    this.appLogic = l;
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) { }
    catch(InvocationTargetException e) { }

    g = getGraphics();
}

public void paint() { ... }

private void createAndShowGUI() {
    final Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());

    final JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
            // if I comment out these lines with the startButton, everything works
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            appLogic.run();
            c.remove(startButton);
        }
    });
    c.add(startButton);

    setSize(FRAME_SIZE, FRAME_SIZE);
    setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In my application logic, I have the following method:

```
public void run() {
    appFrame.paint();
    getNextState();

    // then I added the following code to try and help solve this problem
    System.err.println(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().peekEvent());        
}
```

The output on the System.err stream looks like this:

```
null
null
null
null
null
// here's where I typed command-Q
java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_CLICKED,(210,45),absolute(210,67),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on frame0
java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_CLICKED,(210,45),absolute(210,67),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on frame0
java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_CLICKED,(210,45),absolute(210,67),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on frame0
```

I don't have any mouse listeners in the application (although I assume that the JButton object has one) and I haven't registered any listeners other than the ActionListener on the JButton. And I didn't touch the mouse. But I assume it's all of these MouseEvents that are keeping the application from quitting. Does anybody know what I can do about this? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java/swing: the right action to take upon closing windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540354/java-swing-the-right-action-to-take-upon-closing-windows)

Answer (score 5):

add

```
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

in your `createAndShowGUI()` method.

Comment: I don't think I was necessarily clear -- the program hangs when I try to quit. It looks like, according to the Java documentation, the program is **supposed** to not exit until the AWT event queue is empty, but when I ask the program to quit, for some reason, an infinite number of MouseEvents suddenly and inexplicably appear on the event queue.

Comment: also, explicitly setting `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` made no difference. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Tell the JFrame to exit the JVM when closed.

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

By default, the JFrame just does nothing when closed. Not even quit the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create an extra thread so that I could explicitly separate the application logic processing from the event handling. I don't know why this works, but it seems to have fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the constructor for `MyApplicationFrame`:

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```