# Closing JDialog by button?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

The item menu `About` of my `JFrame` is a `JDialog` that can be closed thanks to a but button as you can see below:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    aboutDialog.this.dispose();
}
```

sometimes when I click on the close button of the `JDialog`, it actually closes the entire program.

I tried:

```
aboutDialog.this.setvisible(true)
aboutDialog.this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
aboutDialog.this.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
aboutDialog.this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

But it didn't worked, any ideas?

Comment: aboutDialog.this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)?

Comment: `sometimes when I click on the close button of the JDialog, it actually closes the entire program.` - this will happen if the dialog is the only open window in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate: [Button for closing a JDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969164/button-for-closing-a-jdialog)
{

```
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class YourDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener{ 

      JButton button;

      public YourDialog() {
         button = new JButton("Close");
         button.addActionListener(this);
         add(button);
         pack();
         setVisible(true);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          dispose();
      }
    }
}
```