# JDialog close if click out of JDialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog

I just want the JDialog to close if I click out of the JDialog

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class DialogFenster extends JDialog {

    public DialogFenster(String pText, String pTitel)
    {
        JDialog meinJDialog = new JDialog();
        meinJDialog.setTitle(pTitel);
        meinJDialog.setBounds(800, 500, 300, 70);
        meinJDialog.setModal(true);
        meinJDialog.add(new JLabel(pText));
        meinJDialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work as there is nothing receiving the click event, and as the dialog is modal nothing else in your app can receive any events.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969164/button-for-closing-a-jdialog

Comment: Make it non modal and intercept onFocusLost. Possibly overlay the main JFrame with a half transparent gray panel receiving the click.

Comment: It sounds like you may want a [Popup](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/PopupFactory.html#getPopup%28java.awt.Component,java.awt.Component,int,int%29) rather than a JDialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WindowListener` in order to know whether the dialog has lost its focus:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, false);//false for not modal
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
        dialog.dispose();
    }
});
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

But it must be a non-modal dialog. If it is modal `windowDeactivated` will never be called.