# Resetting a JDialog after closing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdialog

I am using a `JDialog` to get payment info, `paymentAmount` and `Date` is submitted by a `JTextfield` and a `datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo`.

When the user close the `JDialog` or clicks `Cancel`, `JDialog` closes.But when they click the Payment button and `JDialog` reappears, previously submitted inputs are shown.

I want `JDialog` to be default state whenever it appears.Is there a default way to do this, or i have to create my own reset method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you close a dialog it is not destroyed. It will just become invisible, but it still contains everything as it was when it was closed.

You may override the function `setVisible()` and reinitialize it if the dialog should be shown again.

```
 @Override
 public void setVisible(boolean bVisible)
 {
     if(bVisible == false)
     {
         super.setVisible(bVisible);
         return;
     }

     initMyValues();
     super.setVisible(bVisible);
     return;
 }
```

Alternatively you could create a `WindowListener` and then you get notified about various state changes of the window. Depends on what suits your needs better. The WindowListener doesn't require you to create a separate class, jsut to override the `setVisible()`, but you have to add some extra function required by the interface.

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround would be to set a `windowListener` to your dialog.

```
myDialog.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
            /*Implements over methods here*/
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                //set default values here
            }});
```

Comment: NetBeans auto-generates this kind of code when you create a new JDialog (small difference: it registers a WindowAdapter instead of WindowListener). Could you not also call dispose() in your Payment button event handler after you finished? That was recommended in a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256606/jdialog-setvisiblefalse-vs-dispose