# jtextfield retains value in jdialog after closing jdialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, gui-builder

I'm new to Java and Swing.  I created a jframe and I added a menubar and MenuItem in it.

On clicking a menu item, a jdialog should open. Now the jdialog has a jtextfield in it and a jlabel. Now the problem for me is 'when dialog is opened for first time, the textfield is empty and thats correct. Now i close the jdialog and i open it again but now instead of getting an empty textfield in jdialog, i get the data entered previously' which is not what should happen as the jdialogs 'default close operation' property is set to 'dispose'. but that is not happening for me...

I dont know what i'm doing wrong. I have never tried applet/swing before in any other way (consider this as my first demo learning programme)

[image]
Second Image here

[image: Second Image here]

Comment: Consider using a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)` instead. As for the dialog, either create a new one or (preferable) keep a reference to the text field and set it blank before opening. But for better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) (as opposed to screenshots that tell us almost nothing worth knowing).

Comment: here is my exact problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mfFOG5szvw

Comment: Your exact problem is that you cannot distinguish between Java code and a youtube video. We are unable to help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JTextField` is retaining it's value because it isn't being affected by the `JDialog` closing, instead it is being hidden as it's parent (the `JDialog`) is invisible

Setting the dialog to dispose isn't re-initialising the child components, so they keep their values. Some additional information on this behaviour is available here:

- [JDialog setVisible(false) vs dispose()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256606/jdialog-setvisiblefalse-vs-dispose)
- [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int))

---

One way you can prevent / control this is by "informing" the dialog to wipe the textfield as it is closing by adding a `WindowEvent` and providing the necessary functionality in the `windowClosing()` method

Netbeans gui-builder will generate this for you with the following:

- Right click Dialog

  - Events

    - Window

      - WindowClosing

Providing:

```
private void jDialog1WindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

In which you can add: `textfield.setText("");` to clear the textfield

---

Another approach is to create your own dialog and setting up the components in the constructor. As creating a new instance will contain the components with their default values, effectively resetting it