# How can I add a JMenuItem that closes my Java-program?

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jmenuitem

Do I have to work with an `ActionListener` or `AbstractAction`?

EDITED BASED ON ANSWERS

So, the best way this is the best way to do it?

```
Action closeaction = new AbstractAction("Afsluiten"){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

    };
    menuItem = new JMenuItem(closeaction);
```

Comment: *"Do I have to.."*  Have to?  That is an odd phrase for the common way to do it.

Comment: The general rule is to _always_ go for the highest abstraction available. Here that rule translates to _always_ use an Action. (so it's a clear no for your comment, @SirTroll :-)

Comment: @ kleopatra, so this is the best way to do it?

Comment: It was somebody else. Is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson no it wasn't you :-)

Comment: @kleopatra Oh (disappointed) I'll work on earning the title, just so I can give that reply. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kleopatra comments, [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) is the preferred abstraction, and `AbstractAction` is the right base class. In your handler, a non-zero status signifies an error condition. As an alternative, consider sending a `WINDOW_CLOSING` event, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540802/230513) for `JDialog`.

Addendum: The `WINDOW_CLOSING` event is convenient if your application needs to take some action before terminating. Add a `WindowListener` to the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540802/230513) to see the effect:

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: So, the System.exit(1) is no good way? I have to use WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING?

Comment: Well, use `System.exit(0)` for normal termination; it's just rather abrupt. More above.