# Resizing issue with canvas within jscrollpane within jsplitpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jsplitpane

I'm creating an application using the NetBeans GUI Editor, in which I want to have a `JSplitPane`, the top component of which will be a `Canvas` within a `JScrollPane` and the bottom component will be a `JTextArea`, or something like that.

When I pull the divider downwards, and thus increasing the size of the top component everything seem to resize just fine.

The problem appears when I'm trying to push the divider upwards:
The divider seems to go beneath the `Canvas` (and maybe beneath the `JScrollPane` too).

I have tried various combinations of the preferred/minimum/maximum sizes of the `JScrollPane` and `Canvas` but nothing seems to work.

This is the part of the code that Netbeans generated that may have something to do with the problem at hand:

```
jSplitPane1 = new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
canvas1 = new java.awt.Canvas();
jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

jSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(300);
jSplitPane1.setOrientation(javax.swing.JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(canvas1);

jSplitPane1.setTopComponent(jScrollPane1);

jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
jSplitPane1.setRightComponent(jTextField1);
```

Since this is my first question, I'm not allowed to embed an image in the question, so I will just post the link:

[image]

The red arrows indicate the position of the divider.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Why are using `java.awt.Canvas` instead of `javax.swing.JPanel`?

Comment: Because I'm new to Swing, and canvas seemed the right thing to choose for my purpose, which is to draw shapes on it.
I will take a look to the JPanel as well, to see if it meets my needs.

Comment: It will fit your needs and it is the best choice, since it is not good to mix AWT and Swing components. AWT components should be avoided. I really don't know what to answer since I didn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: The problem is that the canvas will grow larger, but if i want to get it smaller again, it won't resize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the comment by davidbuzatto I googled about mixing AWT and Swing components and I was a little surprissed to find out that it is such a bad practice.

I found the most accurate answer to my question [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14718)

> Heavyweight components have their own Z-ordering. This is the reason why Swing and AWT cannot be combined in a single container. If they are, the AWT components will be drawn on TOP of Swing components.
>
> For example: When AWT components are used with JtabbedPane, they do not disappear when the tabs are switched.

Thanks davidbuzatto for showing me the way :-)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of [`setPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), let your components calculate their own preferred size and `pack()` the enclosing `Window` to accommodate. The example below adds an instance of [`draw.GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) to the top and a corresponding control panel to the bottom.

[image]

```
import draw.GraphPanel;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11942961/230513
 */
public class SplitGraph extends JPanel {

    public SplitGraph() {
        super(new GridLayout());
        JSplitPane split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        GraphPanel graphPanel = new GraphPanel();
        split.setTopComponent(new JScrollPane(graphPanel));
        split.setBottomComponent(graphPanel.getControlPanel());
        this.add(split);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("SplitGraph");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SplitGraph().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, don't let the GUI designer dictate your design.

Comment: That GraphPanel class seems very interesting. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 4):

As I said in my comments, you should not mix AWT and Swing components. I think you are not using the components in the correct way. Take a look, it is a simple example of how to use a JSplitPane.

```
import java.awt.*; // it is necessary to use the Dimension and BorderLayout classes
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo extends JFrame {

    public Foo() {

        setTitle( "Splits" );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setSize( 400, 400 );

        JSplitPane split = new JSplitPane( JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT );
        split.setDividerLocation( 200 );
        add( split );

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        panel1.add( new JLabel( "top panel" ), BorderLayout.NORTH );

        JPanel myDrawPanel = new JPanel();
        myDrawPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 100, 100 ) );
        myDrawPanel.add( new JLabel( "draw panel here!" ) );
        panel1.add( new JScrollPane( myDrawPanel ), BorderLayout.CENTER );

        split.setTopComponent( panel1 );


        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.add( new JLabel( "bottom panel" ) );
        split.setBottomComponent( panel2 );


        setVisible( true );

    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new Foo();
    }

}
```