# Java screen capture App - How to?

Tags: java, image, pdf, screenshot, bufferedimage

i am not a native english speaker so, firstly sorry for the grammar.

I want to do an app that capture a selected area of a screen and save it. I did a few research and i did the code down below.

My questions are:

1 - How can i open a pdf file in this app ? (i tried use a method but it didnt work. I dont know exactly where to put it on the code)

2 - How can i save the selected area in a new file ? (a image file : JPEG, JPG,png)

3 - [the complex part] right now, the code only "save" one selected area each time. I want to capture a lot of parts of screen and save this in the same image file. one beside the other. How can i do this ?

Java Code:

```
package javaapplication39;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScreenCaptureRectangle {

    Rectangle captureRect;

    ScreenCaptureRectangle(final BufferedImage screen) {
        final BufferedImage screenCopy = new BufferedImage(
                screen.getWidth(),
                screen.getHeight(),
                screen.getType());
        final JLabel screenLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(screenCopy));
        JScrollPane screenScroll = new JScrollPane(screenLabel);

        screenScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
                (int)(screen.getWidth()/3),
                (int)(screen.getHeight()/3)));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(screenScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final JLabel selectionLabel = new JLabel(
                "Drag a rectangle in the screen shot!");
        panel.add(selectionLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        repaint(screen, screenCopy);
        screenLabel.repaint();

        screenLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

            Point start = new Point();

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
                start = me.getPoint();
                repaint(screen, screenCopy);
                selectionLabel.setText("Start Point: " + start);
                screenLabel.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                Point end = me.getPoint();
                captureRect = new Rectangle(start,
                        new Dimension(end.x-start.x, end.y-start.y));
                repaint(screen, screenCopy);
                screenLabel.repaint();
                selectionLabel.setText("Rectangle: " + captureRect);
            }
        });

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);

        System.out.println("Rectangle of interest: " + captureRect);
    }

    public void repaint(BufferedImage orig, BufferedImage copy) {
        Graphics2D g = copy.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(orig,0,0, null);
        if (captureRect!=null) {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.draw(captureRect);
            g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,150));
            g.fill(captureRect);
        }
        g.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
                getScreenSize();
        final BufferedImage screen = robot.createScreenCapture(
                new Rectangle(screenSize));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ScreenCaptureRectangle(screen);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 - How can i open a pdf file in this app ? (i tried use a method but it didnt work. I dont know exactly where to put it on the code)

Take a look at [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

> 2 - How can i save the selected area in a new file ? (a image file : JPEG, JPG,png)

Take a look at [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

> 3 - [the complex part] right now, the code only "save" one selected area each time. I want to capture a lot of parts of screen and save this in the same image file. one beside the other. How can i do this ?

Is, as you say, a much more complex question.  You will have to modify the code so that instead of displaying the `panel` in a `JOptionPane`, it shows it within a `JFrame`, you then need to be able to either monitor the `mouseReleaseEvent` or provide some kind of action, may be a toolbar or menu option, that allows the user to save the selection.

Have a look at [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Tool Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for more details.

As a side note, the code will only allow you to capture a single screen, you might consider something like [Drawing a bounding rectangle to select what area to record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948122/drawing-a-bounding-rectangle-to-select-what-area-to-record/13948198#13948198) which will allow you to capture the entire virtual desktop (multiple screeens)

Comment: Thank you, Mad. Can i count with you for future helps?

Comment: I'm ususally lurking about

Comment: Hey, Mad. i changed my plans and i wrote a new topic. Can you see it for me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599834/select-copy-and-paste-images-h-e-l-p

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer, i will bother you for the last time. i swear. How much do you charge to finish this app for me ?? and how can i pay to you ? Thank you.