# How corner points of a shape displayed

Tags: java, swing

I try to write a program to draw a custom shapes and then execute all mouse events like dragging,clicking,moving etc.I want to know that in other editor when any shape is select or mouse is near to there boundary then  its boundary point start to display.I just want the logic not code how corner points displayed like in image? I've done checking that my mouse clicking is inside of shape or not.This is a rounded-rectangle.When I clicked on its rectangle boundary  is start displaying and connection points are also start displaying.How do I do that?
[image]

Comment: You might look at the example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513).

Answer (score 1):

`Shape` interface has `getBounds()` and `contains()` methods. Use `contains()` to determine whether point belongs to the `Shape` and then use `getBounds()` to get rectable and use the rectangle's corners to draw the dragging points.