# Can a rectangle act as a panel?

Tags: java, swing

[image: Figure showing two rectangles which have few other rectangles on them]

I would like to draw rectangles on another rectangle as shown in the figure. So, when I move the rectangle1 or rectangle2, the other rectangles should also move with it. Is there a way to draw rectangles in this way?

Comment: Sure.  Use a translate instance of an `AffineTransform` when drawing at the new position.

Comment: Yes, you can do this.  You would use a JPanel as a canvas.  In your code, you would have to determine whether the rectangle you draw is inside another rectangle or not.  I would create a RectangleObject class, using a Rectangle instance to hold the rectangle parameters.  If the rectangle is inside another rectangle, you'd have to modify the x and y position of the inner rectangle in accordance with the x and y position of the outer rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the outer rectangle represents a *selection rectangle* meant to select the enclosed rectangles, you can maintain a `List<Rectangle>` and update the position of each rectangle as the mouse is dragged. A complete example using `List<Node>` is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513).