# How to attach event handlers to Swing sub components?

Tags: java, swing, awt, listener

I have the following hierarchy with Swing:

```
JFrame
  |
  +---> several JPanes
        one special JPane with a Canvas
         |
         +------> Many Shapes on the Canvas that are derived from JComponents
```

I am confused where to put the Mouse event handlers to detect whether one of the shapes has been clicked. All examples I found so far, attach the event handlers to the root JPane, but since I want to process the events on the circles themselves, it feels quite expensive to loop over all shapes, when a click event on a JPanes is detected.

What is the right approach to have "local" events on the Shapes?

Comment: Best choice is probably to attach the listener to the source component you are most interested in. MouseListeners block those components below, just so your aware...

Comment: Add the listener to the custom `JComponent`(s).

Comment: *"it feels quite expensive to loop over all shapes"*  It would only become relevant if there were *thousands* of them.

Comment: @AndrewThompson is correct; the example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513) scales well into the thousands; beyond that use the flyweight pattern, e.g. [tag:jgraph].