# drawing multiple graphics on the same JLabel

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, java-2d

I am trying to draw a point, a polygon and a rectangle on the same `JLabel` but not really sure how to handle the `paintComponent` method to do so. Currently I am able to draw a point and polygon separately using 2 different classes that extends label, but when I try to put them in the same class because I need both of them on the same label, it starts to draw the polygon and does not allow to draw a point separately.

Here is the code; I need help in debugging the code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.*;

class Drawing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Everything");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Test(new ImageIcon("map.JPG")));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Test extends JLabel
        implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private boolean polygonDrawn = false;
    private final Point trackPoint = new Point();
    private static ArrayList polygonPoints = new ArrayList();
    private static Point point;

    public Test(ImageIcon imageIcon) {
        super(imageIcon, SwingConstants.LEFT);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (point != null) {
            Double x = point.getX();
            Double y = point.getY();
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(x.intValue(), y.intValue(), 5, 5);
        }

        int numPoints = polygonPoints.size();
        if (numPoints == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Point prevPoint = (Point) polygonPoints.get(0);

        Iterator it = polygonPoints.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Point curPoint = (Point) it.next();
            draw(g, prevPoint, curPoint);
            prevPoint = curPoint;
        }
        if (polygonDrawn) {
            draw(g, prevPoint, (Point) polygonPoints.get(0));
        } else {
            draw(g, prevPoint, trackPoint);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(820, 580);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        int x = evt.getX();
        int y = evt.getY();

        switch (evt.getClickCount()) {
            case 1: // single-click
                if (polygonDrawn) {
                    polygonPoints.clear();
                    polygonDrawn = false;
                }
                polygonPoints.add(new Point(x, y));
                repaint();
                break;

            case 2: // double-click
                polygonDrawn = true;
                polygonPoints.add(new Point(x, y));
                repaint();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
        trackPoint.x = evt.getX();
        trackPoint.y = evt.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    private void draw(Graphics g, Point p1, Point p2) {
        int x1 = p1.x;
        int y1 = p1.y;

        int x2 = p2.x;
        int y2 = p2.y;

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(x1 + 3, y1 + 3, x2 + 3, y2 + 3);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x1, y1, 8, 8);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x2, y2, 8, 8);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        point = new Point(x, y);
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: I am sorry Andrew , I forgot to add the main class. The code is edited now.

Comment: You might study the example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513) for examples selecting and dragging shapes in a panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you want to achieve, but note that when drawing the polygon, you are drawing the latest fixed polygon-point on exactly the same place as when drawing the point. To see this, increase the size of the point with

```
g.fillOval(x.intValue(), y.intValue(), 10, 10);
```

and draw the polygon with a different color in the draw method:

```
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: I am aware of that problem and this is what I am trying to fix.I want to draw the point first and then after the point is drawn, At another random location I should be able to draw the polygon and eventually at other random location on the JLabel I should be able to draw a rectangle. How can I draw these multiple graphics on the same JLabel at different positions. However the locations for each of them are not fixed, user can draw at any place.

Comment: Well, I would introduce a state variable (for example an enum) to keep track of what the user is currently doing, and draw accordingly in paintComponent. And in the mouseListener I would manage this state variable.