# How to use a common JComponent object to draw various shapes in swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcomponent

First of, we need a JFrame object.

Then, we create an object of a class extending the JComponent class and inserting the appropriate instructions in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, where g is actually a `Graphics2D` object and attach this to the JFrame object.

Now, what I've been taught is that to draw a rectangle, I do:

```
class RectangleComponent extends JComponent {}
```

Now, to draw a circle, I do:

```
class CircleComponent extends JComponent{}
```

and so on,

However, I want to have one common class that can draw multiple shapes.

I did the following:

```
class Component extends JComponent {
    Shape shape;
    public Component(Shape shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.draw(this.shape);
    }
}
```

In the main, when I get an instruction to draw a rectangle, I do:

```
Shape currentShape = new Rectangle(args);
Component component = new Component(currentShape);
frame.add(component);
```

Immediately following this, I get an instruction to draw a circle and I do:

```
Shape currentShape = new Ellipse2D.Double(args);
Component component = new Component(currentShape);
frame.add(component);
```

Being a rookie that I am, this is where I get lost. I think this makes the **circle overwrite the rectangle**. But that's not my intention. **What should I do to make them both appear together**? I think I should draw them both on the same Component object. But how do I accommodate it in my current implementation?

Comment: Components cannot be stacked on top of one another.  In this case, a single drawing component might keep a list of all the shapes it needs to render. Note:   `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;` should be  `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;`

Comment: What does the extra `super.paintComponent(g);` do? Why is it mandatory? I ask this because my instructor has not mentioned anything about it, neither has this book: Big Java Early Objects

Comment: Which part of [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-) are you confused about?

Comment: The part involving calling the super class method.

Comment: *"Further, if you do not invoker super's implementation you must honor the opaque property, that is if this component is opaque, you must completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts."*  So what don't you understand about that?  Be specific, since I don't intend playing 20 questions.

Comment: A complete example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513).

Comment: @Grendan, you have posted 30 questions on the forum and not once have you "accepted" an answer. Learn how to use the forum properly. "Accepting" an answer is a way to thank people for the help given and a way to let people know a solution has been found.