# Get location of multiple drawings in paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I would need to get the location coordinates of all the drawings I'm creating in the paintComponent method. How can I do this?

Notice that I use the timer to perform some animations so the coordinates change at every tick of the timer.

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 100;
    private int radius = 20;
    private int xDelta = 2;

    public TestPane() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x += xDelta;
                if (x + (radius * 2) > getWidth()) {
                    x = getWidth() - (radius * 2);
                    xDelta *= -1;


                } else if (x < 0) {
                    x = 0;
                    xDelta *= -1;
                }
                label.setText(x+" "+y);
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
```

More code...

```
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Random random = new Random();
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.fillOval(random.nextInt(500), random.nextInt(500) - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);

            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(y, x - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
//            label.setText(label.getText()+ x+" "+y); ;
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(x, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
//            label.setText(label.getText()+ x+" "+y);
        }
```

Comment: *"I would need to get the location coordinates of all the drawings I'm creating.."*  Ummm.. for two of them you are *supplying* the x's any y's, and for the other you can store the `random.nextInt(500)` in a class level attribute before using it..  If that is not a solution to this, I don't understand the question!

Comment: @AndrewThompson I apologise, I added the timer part at the top. So every time the timer ticks the positions are changed.

Comment: See `List<Node>` in the example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I cant see any `List<Node>`

Comment: *"So every time the timer ticks the positions are changed."*  I ..don't see how that changes anything I said earlier. (shrug)  Voting to close as 'unclear what you are asking'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Mmmh... so like I said these are moving objects so the coordinates are changing every iteration of the timer. I want to print or store the coordinates for the three drawings. What is it not clear?

Comment: *"I want to print or store the coordinates for the three drawings. What is it not clear?"*  That's the fist time you've mentioned 'print' (note that though we have super powers, they do **not** include mind reading).  *"..or store.."*  So put the x,y values into a list structure, most easily as a `List<Point>` or `List<Shape>`  ...sheesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program should maintain a `List<Node>` as a class level attribute. Each instance of `Node` should contain the geometry required to render each element in your program.

```
class Node {
    private Point p;
    private int r;
    …
}
```

In your `ActionListener`, update the fields of each `Node` in the `List`. When a `repaint()` occurs, the new positions will be waiting for `paintComponent()` to render.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    …
    for (Node n : nodes) {
        // draw each node
    }
```

A complete example, named `GraphPanel`, is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513).