# How to wrap a jar UI in my java application

Tags: java, swing, executable-jar

I dont know if wrapping is the right word here. Basically I have a java application (app1) with a menu bar and a big Panel. There is another tool (app2) in .jar format which has it own UI. I want to call app2 from app1 so that the UI of app2 opens in app1 defined panel. is this possible?
Many thanks for any suggestion or inputs.

Comment: You want to include the `app2`'s jar file within the classpath of `app1` (AKA a library)

Comment: A detailed answer to this very broad question would depend on the API of the second application.

Comment: @trashgod the app2 jar is a big application with no API documentation, even no comments on code. But anyways, I think you are right I need to go through app2 jar's individual classes and methods. I tried calling app2 from app1, the application opens but not where I wanted.

Comment: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513) may be helpful; also consider whether you could more easily add app1 to app2.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for the link. I will give it a try.