# clarify understanding of Action-event, constructor

Tags: java, swing

I'm confuse on these questions, I was just wondering if anyone see if I'm doing them right.

**If you want to create an effect like a rubber-band line, which changes continually with
user input, you will most likely need a (an)**
A. MouseListener
B. ActionListener
C. MouseAdapter
D. MouseMotionListener
E. KeyListener

I think the answer is action listener because what ever the object is observing generate a action event.

S**uppose a programmer creates a Java class named MyFrame which extends JFrame.
Class MyFrame contains a single constructor whose body is empty. If an object of
type MyFrame is created and made visible (but no other methods in the object are
invoked), then when the user clicks on the “X” in the upper right corner of the window
(frame),**

A. the program will terminate

B. the window will be hidden but will still exist

C. the window will be closed

D. the window will be minimized (“iconified”)

E. the question cannot be answered because such a class cannot be compiled

F. the answer cannot be determined from the information given

Assuming I understood the questions right. So the class MyFram extends to JFrame. And my class MyFrame { } constructor is empty. I think it B, because it will compile, but may not doing any form of action assuming nothing is invoked at all.

Comment: What's a rubber-band line effect?

Comment: Ask your self this, what information would an `ActionListener` give you that would allow you to determine the start point and end point the selection area?

Comment: @Oneiros: A a rubber-band line is one way to effect a GUI selection rectangle; I've cited an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42829574/230513).

Answer (score 1):

As you can read from [official Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)), the default close operation for `JFrame` is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`, so your answer is correct. Extending `JFrame` with `MyFrame` but using an empty constructor makes `JFrame` and `MyFrame` totally equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

A [`MouseMotionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html), such as the `MouseMotionHandler` used during [rubber band selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_banding) in the example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513), allows the view to be updated in its implementation of `mouseDragged()`.

```
private class MouseMotionHandler extends MouseMotionAdapter {
    …
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        …
        e.getComponent().repaint();
    }
}
```