# is there a way to addActionListener to this code

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 5, 5));
    String[] buttons = {
        "1", "2", "3", "/", "4",
        "5", "6", "*", "7", "8", "9", "-", "0", ".", "=", "+"
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            p.add(new JButton(buttons[i]));
   add(p);
```

This code produces a nice calculator layout is there a way to addActionListener to each button while at the same time keeping this layout 
what i mean is not doing it for each and every button like so.

```
JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
     button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
// interesting code for button1 goes here
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did it using this code...

```
   String[] buttons = {
        "1", "2", "3", "/", "4",
        "5", "6", "*", "7", "8", "9", "-", "0", ".", "=", "+"
    };

    Action[] allActions = new Action[buttons.length];

    for ( i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

        allActions[i] = new ButtonAction(buttons[i],i);

        JButton button = new JButton(allActions[i]);

           panel.add(button);


        }
```

with the class ButtonAction as follows

```
  public class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction 
  {
int i;
   public ButtonAction(String text, int i) {
    super(text);
    this.i = i;
    }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    /* you can put any action here. either make the action depend on array value or 
      the string text */
   System.out.println(i);

   }
 }
```

Comment: Also consider `List<Button>`; you can later retrieve any button's action via `getAction()`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, instead of an array of `String`, have an array of [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) instances. Each such `Action` has a name and is also an `ActionListener`. Several examples are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491517/230513).

Comment: i answered it using your suggestion.. i posted answer below

Answer (score 3):

You could simply add an `ActionListener` to each button in your `for` loop in the form of an `AbstractAction`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   JButton button = new JButton(buttons[i]);
   button.addActionListener(new MyAction());
   p.add(button);
}
```

where

```
class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
   ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experience you can create list of buttons and run in loop  to add `ActionListener`:

```
List<JButton> buttonsList = new ArrayList<JButton>(buttons.length):

for (JButton currButton : buttonsList) {

       currButton.addActionListener(){
         ....
       }
   ....
}
```