# How to avoid redundancy in button text while using custom action

Tags: java, swing, action, jbutton

I'm creating a GUI with SWING. Some of the buttons have a custom Action attached.
My code looks like:

```
JButton btn = new JButton(text);
btn.setAction(new MyAction());
```

My action class constructor does:

```
super(text) //set the label of the button
```

My question is: since it seems wrong to me repeat the same parameters (the **text**) two times, how should i handle this? Create the button with no text and let the action set the text (maybe as a constructor parametere)? What is the *correct* way to handle this?
Thanks

Comment: What are you asking. Setting an `Action` as model of a `JButton` will adjust the text of the `JButton` to match the name of the `Action`. So I do not see why you would have to repeat the text twice

Comment: `JButton btn = new JButton(new MyAction());` or if there is also a menu item, `Action action = new MyAction();
JButton btn = new JButton(action);
menu.add(action);`

Comment: I was asking for the most elegant and clear way to do it; basically what Andrew said, thanks.

Comment: +1 for aspiring to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`AbstractAction(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html#AbstractAction%28java.lang.String%29) constructor that includes the `name`. Several examples are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491517/230513).

Addendum: As @MadProgrammer comments, `Action.NAME` is an available `key` for `putValue()`. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) illustrates `putValue()` for other properties.

Comment: Use `new JButton(new MyAction(text))` or use the `Action#NAME` property