# Dealing with LOTS of Key mappings

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, actionevent

What is the best way to define the actions for lots of key mappings for a component in Swing?

I built my own Text View in Swing and want to define actions for a lot of keys. The way I'm currently doing it (for around 10 keys so far) is:

```
ActionMap actionMap = DBDocument.this.getActionMap();
int condition = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED;
InputMap inputMap = DBDocument.this.getInputMap(condition);
String tab = "tab";
actionMap.put(tab, new AbstractAction() {
            private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
            @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ap) {
                if(mDocumentModel != null){
                    //Do some stuff here
                }
             }
          });
```

This is obviously a very verbose way of defining key bindings. Ideally I would be able to define an action that deals with lots of possibilities (e.g. [A-Z] or [0-9]). I've searched for definitions in the OpenJDK but didn't get very far.

Comment: put all  ["LOTS of Key mappings" to array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7940227/714968), use one array for plain keys [A-Z]/[0-9], second for modifier + key (e.g. ALT + [A-Z]/[0-9]), etc

Comment: and to use is/setEnabled for your XxxAction

Answer (score 1):

Kudos for avoiding repetition by applying the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle. Several examples of DRY actions are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491517/230513), but the common thread is actions that share a common model, such as `Document`, or are shared by a group of related buttons.